# Are there any reserved keywords for attribute values in HTML?

Tags: html, tags, reserved-words

I mean, are there any words that we shouldn't use as the `<tag class='reserved' />`, class, id or any other thing?

I was planning to style the links with class "link", is this a good idea?

Answer (score 5):

There are no reserved keywords for the `class` attribute, with the caveat that using special characters other than letters, numbers, or the underscore in the name, or beginning the name with a number, makes using it as a CSS selector more difficult.

Check out [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes):

> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to.
>   ...
>   There are no additional restrictions on the tokens authors can use in the `class` attribute, but authors are encouraged to use values that describe the nature of the content, rather than values that describe the desired presentation of the content.

... where [a set of space-separated tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#set-of-space-separated-tokens) is exactly what you'd think and has no other restrictions.

#### When the class is used as a CSS selector...

... the [CSS grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner) comes into play. A CSS name can contain:

- alphanumeric characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- the underscore `_`
- the hyphen `-`
- select non-ASCII/extended ASCII characters (octal `\240-\377` — includes common symbols, letters with diacritics, etc.)
- or a character escaped by `\`. Escaped characters can be a Unicode code point (up to six bytes, terminated by whitespace, such as a regular space `" "`, if needed) or a non-alphanumeric character.

In addition, the name can't start with a (literal) number or hyphen, so those must be escaped. Because the escaped character must not be alphanumeric (specifically `0-9` or `a-f`, to differentiate from Unicode points, I assume), the Unicode value must be used if the selector name begins with a number.

Example (noting that `\32` is the Unicode value for `2`):

```
...
<style>
  .\32 34 { color: red; }
  .big-\$-G { color: green; } /* the color of money */
</style>
...
<div class="234">Some text here.</div>
<div class="big-$-G">This is in the "big-$-G" class.</div>
...
```

---

In my opinion, using "link" as a class name for links is fine, as long as it applies to all links you'll be defining. Otherwise, use something like "importantLinks", "mainLinks", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is ok to use word `link` for class naming.
However, try to give it more explicit name so it not conflict with other code in the future.

Just go in source of such framework as [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and see how they name their classes.

Use namespasing

Answer (score 0):

In the case of JavaScript and ‍‍‍JSX (JavaScript XML), there are some HTML attributes which only reserved for JavaScript, not for JSX. Such as `class` and `for`.